# Android crash when adding LiveData observer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm trying to get a LiveData Observer to work, and everything was working, but after a week my app keeps crashing when attaching the fragment to my activity with the live data. The fragment is very simple, it has a RecyclerView that displays a list of `Bloggers` in a grid. The ViewModel is the following:

```
class SimpleBloggersViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var bloggers: MutableLiveData<List<Blogger>> = MutableLiveData()
}
```

And I initialize it in my fragment using:

```
private val viewModel: SimpleBloggersViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this).get(SimpleBloggersViewModel::class.java)
}
```

The code that causes the crash is the following:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
        viewModel.bloggers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { changeObserver })
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: Failed to attach BloggersFragment.", e)
    }
}
```

Without the try/catch in the `onAttach` method, I get the following cryptic exception (and an app crash)

```
Process: com.mydomain.appname, PID: 31393
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.attachController(FragmentManager.java:3000)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:2622)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1291)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1264)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1147)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:120)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2369)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2327)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2230)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.run(FragmentManager.java:414)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

After adding the try/catch block you see above, the exception ahs a little bit more info, but I still can't figure out what causes the problem.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can consumeRestoredStateForKey only after super.onCreate of corresponding component
    at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.consumeRestoredStateForKey(SavedStateRegistry.java:77)
    at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:65)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:177)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:145)
    at com.mydomain.appname.Bloggers.BloggersFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(BloggersFragment.kt:31)
    at com.mydomain.appname.Bloggers.BloggersFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(BloggersFragment.kt:28)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.mydomain.appname.Bloggers.BloggersFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.mydomain.appname.Bloggers.BloggersFragment.onAttach(BloggersFragment.kt:90)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:2638)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1291)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1264)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1147)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:120)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2369)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2327)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:236)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6682)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6682)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6682)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6682)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:743)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6682)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6682)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6682)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6682)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
2019-09-19 12:18:11.181 31963-31963/com.mydomain.appname E/BloggersFragment:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6682)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:725)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2531)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1558)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1826)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1446)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7014)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:916)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:728)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:660)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:902)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

Please note that I call super on all of the overriding methods, before doing anything else, so the second exception still doesn't help me figure the bug out. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try observing the livedata in `onActivityCreate`

Comment: Check out the fragment lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png

Comment: Check when viewModel is first being referenced, I suspect it is before the fragment has completed the creation stage of it's lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you so much @sonnet, the example I've followed had the observer in `onAttach`, but the official Android docs have it in `onActivityCreate` as you've suggested. You saved me from a growing headache.